# PHP PDO insert fails causing infinite loop

Tags: php, pdo

The following seems to produce an endless loop but I can seem to figure out why it's not working. I know that the insert is not working but I can't figure out why. I've tried the query out in phpmyadmin and it works fine.

```
function generate_cart_id($dbh) {

        //generate cart_id and check against assigned_carts to make sure it's unique
        $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $stmt=$dbh->prepare("insert into assigned_carts (cart_id,ip,date) values (:cart_id,:ip,now())");
        $stmt->bindValue(':ip',$ip, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        do {
                $cart_id=mt_rand(100000000,9999999999);
                $stmt->bindValue(':cart_id',$cart_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        }
        while ($stmt->execute()==false);
        return $cart_id;
}
```

**Here's what I came up with in the end.**

```
function generate_cart_id($dbh) {   
    $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $stmt=$dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO assigned_carts (cart_id,ip,date) Value ((select * from (SELECT FLOOR(100000000 + RAND() * 899999999) as ar From assigned_carts where 'ar' NOT IN (Select cart_id FROM assigned_carts) LIMIT 1) as x) ,:ip,now())");
    $stmt->bindValue(':ip',$ip, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    try {
        $stmt->execute();
        $id=$dbh->lastInsertID(); //You cannot retreive a randomly generated id with last id. Only an autoincremented one so I added that and used a select to get the random one.
        $row=$dbh->query("select cart_id from assigned_carts where id=$id")->fetch();

        return $row['cart_id'];
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
        // do something
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your loop is backwards. it terminates on success (good), but continues executing on failure (bad). if the query fails, you try the query again, which fails, which runs again, blah blah blah.

Comment: That's what it is suppose to do. It fails on a duplicate row so it tries another cart_id.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why don't you use a SELECT statement to grab all the cart_ids and then use PHP to generate a cart_id that isn't in that list? It should be more efficient that way.

Comment: No because the chances for the cart_id already having already been used are remote.

Comment: @code: yes, but it'll still loop if the query fails for other reasons. e.g. let's say mysql dies. you've now got an infinite loop because the query call returns falls. you'd be better off checking error codes. a unique key violation has error code 1022. As well, why not simply use the last_insert_id to get a unique cart id, without all those looping garbage? if you're worried about guessable IDs, you can always use a crypt function to mangle the ID into something less guessable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a strictly PDO-based solution, but you could try something like this:

```
// grab list of all cart_id ids
$qry = 'SELECT cart_id FROM assigned_carts'
      .' WHERE cart_id >= 100000000 && cart_id <= 9999999999';
$all_cart_ids = $dbh->exec($qry);

// generate a random number that's not in that list
while($cart_id === NULL || in_array($cart_id, $all_cart_ids)){
    $cart_id=mt_rand(100000000,9999999999);
}

// insert
$stmt=$dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO assigned_carts (cart_id,ip,date) VALUES (:cart_id,:ip,now())");
$stmt->bindValue(':ip',$ip, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':cart_id',$cart_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
try {
    $stmt->execute();
    return $cart_id;
}
catch(PDOException $e){
    // do something
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: The insert is still failing but the infinite loop is gone. I guess the insert is a separate issue so this answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

try something like

```
if ($stmt->execute()) {
    // Query succeeded.
} else {
    // Query failed.
    $errorcode = $stmt->errorCode();
}
```

or

```
if ($sql->execute === false) {    //false on error
     var_dump($sql->errorinfo();  //array containing information on error
     die()
}
```

**BEST** try something like

```
function getData($db) {
   $stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM table");
   return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

//then much later
try {
   getData($db);
} catch(PDOException $ex) {
   //handle me.
}
```

**Good Read**

[**PDO Tutorial for MySQL Developers**](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers)